# jQuery sortables - connect problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sortables

I have two examples on jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/9uhfX/1/
- http://jsfiddle.net/9uhfX/2/

**Example 1**

In the first one I can move the list elements around, even from a child element to the root element. However, it's not very easy to make it "snap".

**Example 2**

In the second example I have floated the list elements. This time I can't get them to "snap" to the child elements.

**Questions**

- Is there a good way to make it easier to snap?
- How do I solve it with float?

Comment: I'm not understanding the question.  In your two examples, the only difference I can see is that one is horizontal and the other vertical.  I can move elements in/out of the children on both.

Comment: I can move them side by side in the second one but have problems by moving them inside of other elements.

Comment: In my opinion (with Safari), they are working 100% identically.  #2 is more difficult to use simply because it has a smaller "drop zone" due to its layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a so far undocumented option in jQuery sortable to define the element against which tolerance is checked: `toleranceElement`. If not set, the whole item is checked for placement (including the nested list), but if it's set, only sub-items matching the selector are taken into account.

This means you have to change your HTML markup a bit to wrap the main content of the list item (the item text in your case) in an element and use that to check for sort positioning. That will leave out the nested `<ul>`s, effectively stopping jittering which is otherwise quite serious.

HTML:

```
<div id="example5"> 
    <ul> 
        <li ><div>Item 1</div>
            <ul> 
                <li ><div>Item 1 1</div><ul></ul></li> 
                <li ><div>Item 1 2</div><ul></ul></li> 
                <li ><div>Item 1 3</div><ul></ul></li> 
            </ul> 
        </li> 
        <li ><div>Item 2</div><ul></ul></li> 
        <li ><div>Item 3</div><ul></ul></li> 
        <li ><div>Item 4</div><ul></ul></li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#example5 ul").sortable({
    connectWith: "#example5 ul",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    toleranceElement: 'div'
});
```

Try your modified demos [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9uhfX/5/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9uhfX/4/).

You might also want to play with `opacity`, `cursorAt` and `tolerance`. Have a look at the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/).

Note that it's not a perfect solution, in case you're not satisfied with the results, have a look at using a plugin. Manuele J Sarfatti's `nestedSortable` plugin looks like something that might be of use for you: http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at both of your examples in Safari and I am able to move any element in/out of the children elements without a huge problem.

Here is why #2 is more difficult to use...

The "drop zone" in example #2 is only as high as your element so with your short elements, there is a much smaller area to get your mouse into.

The "drop zone" in example #1 is very wide so it's very easy to hit it as you move your mouse up/down the list.

The only way I can think of to solve your problem is to simply make your items in example #2 taller, thereby simulating what you have in example #1 except on its side.

[**http://jsfiddle.net/9uhfX/3/**](http://jsfiddle.net/9uhfX/3/)